# APNSwork on apn provider but not through nodeJS - Production

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I have a nodeJS script set up to send APNs. When in development it always works but when i go to production they never get through. I tried taking the same notification Id it's sending and sending something using my production certificate in Easy Apn Provider and and it goes through. Im not sure why i could be failing. If my profile or certificates were wrong the easy apn wouldnt go through either?

[image: Easy apn successfully sent]

apn config

```
var options = {
    token: {
    cert: "certificate.pem",
    pfx: "Certificate.p12",
    key: "AuthKey_XCVK62CSQF.p8",
    keyId: "3Z6SEF7GE5",
    teamId: "ASQJ3L7765"
    },
    production: true,
     gateway: 'gateway.push.apple.com',      // gateway address
     port: 2195
   };
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
```

Result of:

```
//IOS notif function
function SendIOSNotification(token, message, sound, payload, badge){
var deviceToken = token; //phone notification id
var notification = new apn.Notification(); //prepare notif
notification.topic = 'com.GL.Greek-Life'; // Specify your iOS app's Bundle ID (accessible within the project editor)
notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Set expiration to 1 hour from now (in case device is offline)
notification.badge = badge; //selected badge
notification.sound = sound; //sound is configurable
notification.alert = message; //supports emoticon codes
notification.payload = {id: payload}; // Send any extra payload data with the notification which will be accessible to your app in didReceiveRemoteNotification
    apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then(function(result) {  //send actual notifcation
    // Check the result for any failed devices

    var subToken = token.substring(0, 6);
    console.log("Succesfully sent message to ", subToken);
    }).catch( function (error) {
            console.log("Faled to send message to ", subToken);
    })
}
```

is successfully sent message to 5D..

Edit:
When displaying my response i see that the notification actually failed with a 403 error (id doesnt exist however it works just fine with easy apn).

I assume its because im generating a non production id but i dont understand how thats possible. I signed my build and have it on testflight and ive removed all signes of development profiles and only have production profiles and certificates. Not sure how thiis is happening

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when i changed to production and it wasnt working I tried creating a new .p8 key. It was likely working at that point but i only changed the reference to .p8 and not the key parameter to the key of the .p8 found on my developer account. Once i updated that key all my problems were solved